# Overlaying an element over a duplicate in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery menu in the following page:

[Menu](http://tranceil.fm/new/?page_id=837)

As you can see i duplicated the menu 2 times because i need more items and control over each menu block.

But when hovering over them you can see the duplicate in the background.

How can i overlay one on top of each other if they all holds the same CSS class?

Comment: You need to include code in your original post, simply linking to it will get you downvoted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you make two CSS classes and then use http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Yup i was thinking of this but i thought to ask first if theres a different approach. i went with your option, Thanx m8